# QPSK Data transfer, No useful signal while trying to measure SNR

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I am trying to find a reliable way to measure good SNR and found the MPSK SNR Estimator is probably my best shot. Getting 2 decimal places would be the goal but it looks far away for now.

I based my project on this tutorial https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php?title=QPSK_Mod_and_Demod#Receiving_a_QPSK_signal and the theory without sending the data works great. When I hook up my USRPs it goes haywire.

1. I am not quite sure about the sample rates since I only got them by trial and error. I always had a lot of underflows or overflows in the USRP Sink if I used the same sample rate everywhere.
2. I am not sure why the signal is not transmitted correctly. A signal is transmitted but it appears to not contain any information.

[image: Flowchart]

[image: Outgoing vs Incoming]

Thanks for any help!